# applying 2 grep conditions in perl

Tags: regex, perl

My dataset (csv file) contains a large number of individuals undergoing several tests. If the any of the tests is done the test date will be there. On the second column there is the code of the organization to which the individual pertains. We have around 40 unique codes/organizations. I am trying in that large dataset to check all the unique codes then for each organization(i.e unique code) get a file containing all the organization specific data. Note I also need to get the date in the form of month-year rather than day-month-year.
here's a feel of how my dataset look like:

```
Patient,Code,test1,test2,test3 
P1,072,,25-Mar-14,                                          
P2,072,29-May-14,,                                           
P3,073,,03-Jan-14,                                  
P4,074,,,16-Feb-14                                           
P5,075,,09-Jul-14,                                          
P6,075,08-Jun-14,,
```

the output should be something like that:
a file with 072 containing title that looks like that:

```
Patient,Code,test1,test2,test3 
P1,072,,25-Mar-14,                                          
P2,072,29-May-14,,
```

Another file with 073 title that looks similar to that:

```
Patient,Code,test1,test2,test3 
P3,073,,03-Jan-14,
```

etc

here's the code I have written. It saves the unique codes and creates a csv file with the organization specific code but does not fill each file with the appropriate info (data pertaining only to that specific organization and substitute dd-mm-yy with mm-yy. Anyone could tell me what is wrong with the code?

```
use feature ':5.12';
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $dataset          = 'R:/dataset/';
my $output_directory = 'R:/results/';

open my $infh, '<', "$dataset/CH_dataset.csv";

my %codes = ();
while (<$infh>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = split ",";
    print "$columns[1]\n" if !$codes{ $columns[1] }++;
    my @unique_codes = keys %scodes;

    foreach my $unique_codes (@unique_codes) {
        open my $outfh, ">>", "$output_directory/CH_$unique_codes\_v$version.$update.csv";
        print $outfh $_
            if (/"$unique_codes"/
            and s/\d\d\-Jan\-/Jan\-/g | s/\d\d\-Feb\-/Feb\-/g | s/\d\d\-Mar\-/Mar\-/g | s/\d\d\-Apr\-/Apr\-/g
            | s/\d\d\-May\-/May\-/g | s/\d\d\-Jun\-/Jun\-/g | s/\d\d\-Jul\-/Jul\-/g | s/\d\d\-Aug\-/Aug\-/g
            | s/\d\d\-Sep\-/Sep\-/g | s/\d\d\-Oct\-/Oct\-/g | s/\d\d\-Nov\-/Nov\-/g | s/\d\d\-Dec\-/Dec\-/g );
    }
}
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: for example a csv file with the code 072 in the title and the following insidePatient Code    test1   test2   test3 
P1  072     25-Mar-14                                           
P2  072 29-May-14

Comment: Why are you spliting on `,`? Your columns seem separated by space(s).

Comment: @M42 my dataset set is actually in a csv format. I have edited how it looks above

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task once. I used a hash to hold all the required filehandles and close
them all just before exiting. The code below should work if your data adheres to a strict format.

```
use 5.14.0;
use Carp;

my $infile = $ARGV[0];

my %fh;    # this hash will have your codes as keys and the
           # corresponding filehandles as values.

# {{{ Open the infile and work
open( INFILE, "<$infile" ) or croak("Could not open $infile");
my $lineCnt = 0;
my $header  = readline(INFILE);    # skip the first line.
chomp($header);
my $justOpened = 0;
while ( my $line = readline(INFILE) ) {
    chomp($line);
    if ( $line =~ m/^\s*\#/ or $line =~ m/^\s*$/ ) { next; }
    my @ll = split( /,/, $line );
    my $code = $ll[1];
    my $dmy;
    for my $temp (@ll) {
        if ( $temp =~ m/\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{2}/ ) {
            $dmy = $temp;
        }
    }
    my @dmy = split( /-/, $dmy );
    my $nmy = $dmy[1] . '-' . $dmy[2];
    $line =~ s/$dmy/$nmy/;
    unless ( exists( $fh{$code} ) ) {
        my $fn = "code" . $code . '.csv';
        open( $fh{$code}, ">", $fn );
        $justOpened = 1;
    }
    select( $fh{$code} );
    if ($justOpened) {
        print("$header\n");
        $justOpened = 0;
    }
    print("$line\n");
}
close(INFILE);
# }}}

# {{{ close all the filehandles before exiting.
for my $handle ( values(%fh) ) {
    close($handle);
}
# }}}

exit;
```

Comment: @Miller, your solution is definitely good but it involves opening (or reopening) of files at _every_ line of input. When I had to do something similar, the input data files were absolutely huge (10 to 20 Gb each) and several of them. It was then that I discovered that opening files is actually quite a slow operation and came up with my little scheme of keeping open file handles as values of a hash. It is slightly more complicated but definitely speeded things up significantly for me.

Comment: You are correct.  If the files are large, then caching the file handles makes sense and is relatively easy to do.   However, that does introduce the potential concern of how many file handles the problem might require, and the potential need to adjust the ulimit.  Given the description, I suspect the size/speed is not actually a huge concern.

Answer (score 0):

The description of your goal is clear.  However, your code appears rather malformed.

Instead of trying to parse out where your programming is going wrong, I'm just going to demonstrate how I would approach the problem:

```
use feature ':5.12';
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $dataset          = 'R:/dataset/';
my $output_directory = 'R:/results/';

#open my $infh, '<', "$dataset/CH_dataset.csv";
my $infh = \*DATA;

my $header = <$infh>;

my %codes = ();
while (<$infh>) {
    chomp;
    my $code = ( split ',' )[1];

    #my $outfile = "$output_directory/CH_${code}_v$version.$update.csv";
    my $outfile = "CH_${code}.csv";

    my $outfh;
    if ( !-e $outfile ) {
        open $outfh, '>', $outfile;
        print $outfh $header;
    } else {
        open $outfh, '>>', $outfile;
    }

    # Remove Day of Month
    s/\d{2}-(?=(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2})//g;

    print $outfh "$_\n";
}

__DATA__
Patient,Code,test1,test2,test3 
P1,072,,25-Mar-14,                                          
P2,072,29-May-14,,                                           
P3,073,,03-Jan-14,                                  
P4,074,,,16-Feb-14                                           
P5,075,,09-Jul-14,                                          
P6,075,08-Jun-14,,
```

Outputs 4 files:

```
$ ls CH_07*
CH_072.csv  CH_073.csv  CH_074.csv  CH_075.csv

$ cat CH_07*
Patient,Code,test1,test2,test3 
P1,072,,Mar-14,                                          
P2,072,May-14,,                                           
Patient,Code,test1,test2,test3 
P3,073,,Jan-14,                                  
Patient,Code,test1,test2,test3 
P4,074,,,Feb-14                                           
Patient,Code,test1,test2,test3 
P5,075,,Jul-14,                                          
P6,075,Jun-14,,
```